# PRAW Get message author?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm trying to build a when I get a message on Reddit to display an alert on my device and tell it the author. Something like this:

[image]

I tried searching for Reddit's documentation but I didn't find anything on the matter including the PRAW's docs, Reddit's API docs, and on their Subreddit. I even tried `messages.author` but that didn't work out either. What I want to get is this: [image] So far the code looks like this:

```
import praw
import time
import os
import pync
from pync import Notifier

print "Booting up..."

def Main():
    print "Searching for messages..."
    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='RedditNotifier version 0.0.1')
    r.login('username', 'pass')
    for msg in r.get_unread(limit=None):
        if not msg:
            print "True"
        else:
            Notifier.notify('From:' + 'Author here', title='Reddit: New Message!', open='https://www.reddit.com/message/unread/')
            print msg
while True:
    Main()
    time.sleep(5)
```

TL;DR How to get message author using PRAW

EDIT: Image only serves to show progress so far
Thanks!

Comment: you won't find a messaging utility in praw or reddit's documentation - that's not what either of them does

Comment: So I can't do that. Should I scrape the data then?

Comment: No, I mean the notification bar. If I've misunderstood your question, then you should learn [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `Main()` is not a class so don't capitalize it's name. It's against PEP 8, Python's official style guide.

Comment: Oh ok I'll not capitalize it anymore, It was about getting the author's name who messages me and then display it like that

Comment: let's clarify: are you asking about how to display the message or the author?

Comment: Author! just put that on my progress so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PRAW: Comment Submitter's Username](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822808/praw-comment-submitters-username)

Comment: what does my answer not make clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120158/discussion-between-uohtypyzarc-and-unknowndeveloper).

Comment: PLEASE DON'T USE ALL CAPS!!! (capitalized for ironic effect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you couldn't find it in the PRAW docs because a quick google search "praw author" gave me this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20939233/1459669) answer.

A comment has an `author` attribute, which is a `Redditor` object. And to get the name from the `Redditor` object, use its `name` attribute.

EDIT: So what you to do is replace`'Author here'` with `msg.author.name`